# How to define an implicit conversion for typedefs?

Tags: c++, casting

I want to have an automatic conversion from `std::string` into my type `my_type`, defined as

`typedef std::pair<std::string,int> my_type;`

such that the `.first` part of the converted `my_type` is the string and the `.second` part is always 0.

It should also work if one calls the function `std::string fun(my_type x, ...) { return x.first; }` with, say,

`std::string s = "Hello"; fun(s, ...);`.

I don't want to define a new class instead of `my_type` and also not to overload all of my functions if possible. I tried to wrap my head around how to use `operator` for this but I can't get my program to compile.

**EDIT:**
Since this doesn't seem to be possible without defining a custom struct or so, here is a workaround that I came up with, but I was hoping it can be achieved without defining a new class/struct. Thank you for saving me more time trying to do this, though.

```
class Element {
  public:
    Element() {};
    Element(std::string s, int a) { name = s; value = a; };
    Element(std::string s) { name = s; value = 0; };
    ...
    std::string return_name() { return name; };
  private:
    std::string name;
    int value;
 };

std::string fun(Element x) { return x.return_name(); };
```

Calling `std::string s = "Hello"; fun(s);` works now automatically.

Comment: It can't be done. Find a workaround.

Comment: You either need to overload or make your own type with a conversion operator.  Those are the only options.

Comment: “Implicit typecast” is a contradiction. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. It is always explicit. The term you want is “implicit conversion”.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add new implicit conversions for existing classes, such as `std::pair`. Implicit conversions can only be member functions:

- A non-explicit constructor that can be called with one argument. If there are more arguments, they must have default values.
- `operator T() const` conversion operator.

And it is not possible to add new member functions to classes without changing class definition. This restriction is in place to prevent a function introduced at global or namespace scope from changing the semantics of your existing code.

---

What you can do instead is create a new class with a conversion constructor (a non-explicit constructor that can be called with one argument):

```
struct MyPair : std::pair<std::string, int> {
    // In this class scope pair now refers to std::pair<std::string, int>.

    MyPair(std::string const& a)
        : pair(a, 0)
    {}

    MyPair(pair const& a)
        : pair(a)
    {}
};
```

The derivation from `std::pair<std::string, int>` makes it possible to pass `MyPair` where `std::pair<std::string, int>` is expected. And another constructor for converting `std::pair<std::string, int>` to `MyPair`.